# How to change the like and unlike text to a svg or iframe heart in the ajax code?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

> I am trying to change the like and unlike text that displays when a user clicks the svg heart-fill. What I am expecting is that the heart changes color rather than changing to the like and unlike text in the ajax code. I have tried changing the `.text` to `.html` but it doesn't work, my ajax knowledge is not strong.
> Here is the code below:

*HTML:*

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'like' %}" class="like-form" id="{{post.id}}"> 
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{post.id}}>
    <div>
      <span class="like-count{{post.id}}">{{ post.total_likes }}</span>
      <button  class="btn btn-link text-dark p-0 border-0 btn-outline-light like-btn{{post.id}}">
        {% if user in post.liked.all %}
            <svg class="redme{{post.id}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="red" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path id="path" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
            </svg>
        {% else %}
            <svg class="greyme{{post.id}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="grey" class="bi bi-heart-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path id="path1" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 1.314C12.438-3.248 23.534 4.735 8 15-7.534 4.736 3.562-3.248 8 1.314z"/>
            </svg>
        {% endif %}
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

*JS:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on('click', function() {
      $("svg path").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('class') === 'is-colorized'){
          $(this).attr('class', '');
        }else {
          $(this).attr('class', 'is-colorized');
        }
      })
    });

    $('.like-form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      const post_id = $(this).attr('id')

      const likeText = $(`.like-btn${post_id}`).text()
      console.log(likeText)
      const trim = $.trim(likeText)
      const url = $(this).attr('action')
      
      let res;
      const likes = $(`.like-count${post_id}`).text()
      const trimCount = parseInt(likes)
      console.log(trimCount)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
              'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
              'post_id': post_id,
            },
            success: function(response){
              if(trim === 'Unlike'){
                $(`.like-btn${post_id}`).text('Like'); //I want to change like to svg or iframe heart
                res = trimCount - 1
              }
              else {
                $(`.like-btn${post_id}`).text('Unlike'); //I want to change**strong text** like to svg or iframe heart
                res = trimCount + 1
              }
              $(`.like-count${post_id}`).text(res)
            },
            error: function(response){
              console.log('error', response)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just replacing the color like this?

```
success: function(response){
    let button = $(`.like-btn${post_id}`)
    if(trim === 'Unlike'){
        button.html(button.html().replace("red", "gray"));
        res = trimCount - 1
    }
    else {
        button.html(button.html().replace("gray", "red"));
        res = trimCount + 1
    }
    $(`.like-count${post_id}`).text(res)
},
```

`button.html()` is the getter/setter for the innerHtml. So the code retrives the svg code, replaces the color name and writes the changed svg code back to the button.

Comment: The colour effect works fine but the logic of adding and removing the user changes. It keeps increasing the number of likes as the user keeps clicking the heart svg instead of removing and adding as the user clicks.